# What do you do in case you have worked for 4 months don’t have 5th month salary slip but have experience letter of 5 months?

Tags: salary, resignation, work-experience, india

I have worked with a consultancy for 4 months and my Team Leader misbehaved with me so I absconded and after 20 days I have written a resignation mail to my HR.

For that month (5th month) I didn't receive any salary but in my experience letter it is mentioned that i have 5 months of experience.

So will it work in another organisation showing 5 months experience but having 4 month salary.?

Also I was in training period at that time and only letter of engagement was provided so will it be sufficient for joining new company.

Comment: Welcome to Workplace SE! I've given your question a quick edit to help clear it up and improve readability. Also based on some of the terms you use talking about experience letters etc I'm assuming this is in India? I've taken the liberty of tagging the question as such - if I've gotten that wrong I apologise and you can edit/re-tag as appropriate.

Comment: It might not have been a good idea to post this using your real name & photo

Answer (score 2):

> *So will it work in another organisation showing 5 months experience but having 4 month salary.?*

That really really depends on the *another organization*.

Speaking from the work experience in India, the tenure mentioned in the experience letter takes the priority. Salary slips / paycheks are *not mandatory* to prove your employment (and they are not to be distributed freely, like many do), the company provided experience letter is sufficient.

That said, whether you claim the experience  for a period of 4 months or 5 - rarely matters - there's usually no groundbreaking difference that comes out of 1 more (or less) month of employment. In practice, many organizations consider 0-2 years of work to be in the same bucket of experience - junior positions (also known as "freshers").

Comment: I'm curious, why would you need paychecks to get a new job ?

Comment: @Rolexel Me too, but sadly, that seems to be the norm in India. I asked around, but nobody was able to provide me an answer, let alone a reliable one.

Comment: From other posts in this stack I gathered that in India potential employers like to give you a salary proposition just above your previous salary independently of the market or you skills. That and it seems that some company ask for original of documents to later blackmail soon to be ex-employee by withholding them.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain the reason behind the act? Thanks.